# Contactform 7 - require email or phone

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I’m trying to figure out how I can require the phone number OR the email. I found a post earlier on `wordpress.org` but I can’t figure out the documentation of this module.

Anyone that can help me?

I used the text-or.php module found on [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-two-required-fields-but-only-one-must-be-filled/).

Anyone got some other modules or an example of how to require phone OR email?

Comment: One more way to add some code in `function.php` or create shortcode or add some code in contact form 7 plugin `text.php` file.

Comment: [email*] [phone*] this is the way to setup required field in contact form 7

Comment: If you want to required a field on Contact Form 7, you just write like this [email*], [name*] that all